# How to display end date in Woocommerce Subscriptions with a specific date format?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, date-formatting, woocommerce-subscriptions

I just want to ask on how to display the end date (or next payment date) in Woocommerce Subscriptions in "MM/DD/YYYY" format?

I'm currently using WooCommerce, WooCommerce Subscriptions, WooCommerce Memberships and Elementor Pro (with Dynamic Content for Elementor plugin).

I was able to display the End date of the subscription, but I just don't know on how to display it in a specific date format.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$users_subscriptions = wcs_get_users_subscriptions($user_id);

foreach ($users_subscriptions as $subscription){
  if ($subscription->has_status(array('active'))) {

         echo $subscription->get_date('end'); 
  }
}
```

The code displays the necessary date, but I need to display the date in "MM/DD/YYYY" format. As of now, Its displaying in "MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS".

I hope anyone could help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert `$subscription->get_date('end')` to the format that you need using [`date`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

So, replace this line:

```php
echo $subscription->get_date('end'); // Returns "MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS" (i.e Jan-21-2022 09:35:37)
```

With this line:

```php
echo date('M/d/Y', strtotime($subscription->get_date('end'))); // Returns "MM/DD/YYYY" (i.e Jan/21/2022)
```

Or if you need to show it like `01/21/2022`, then use the following:

```php
echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($subscription->get_date('end')));
```